# Returning a malloced pointer from a function , does it cause memory leak?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, memory-leaks, malloc

I have a function foo like

```
myType** foo(){

    myType **array = malloc( .... );
    //Do some stuff
    return array;
}
```

Here I have malloced , but did not free it as I am returning it . Will this cause a memory leak ? Should I explicitly free it in the calling function after I use it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a memory leak only if you don't free the memory (regardless where).

In this case, you should `free` it after the function is called and you're done with the pointer.

But this is the C way of doing it. In C++ you'd return a smart pointer, and use `new` instead of `malloc`.

Answer (score 5):

With this type of function, the caller is the "owner" of the resources pointed at by the pointer. So the caller has to either free the resources, or pass them on to someone else who will.

In C++ one would favour returning a type that manages its own resources, for example an `std::vector`, or a [smart pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), that both takes care of resource de-allocation and makes the ownership clear.

See this example,and don't worry, read all about [copy elision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_elision), particularly *named return value optimization* (NRVO).

```
std::vector<std::vector<SomeType>> foo()
{
  std::vector<std::vector<SomeType>> tmp = ....;
  // do some stuff
  return tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Memory leaks are caused by not freeing memory. As long as the memory *will* get freed at some point, then it isn't leaked. But if the pointer ever gets "lost" or if some sort of dependency loop causes a situation where the memory stays around even after it is no longer useful, then at that point you've created a leak.

Usually in this type of situation, you create a pattern like this:

```
void* mything_init() {
   void *obj = malloc(LEN);
   // do some initialization
   return obj;
}

void mything_uninit(void* thing) {
   // any teardown
   free(thing);
}
```

For every `mything` that you `_init`, you must eventually call `_uninit` on that object. That is your responsibility as the user of that library. While as the writer of that library, you make sure that anything you allocate in the `_init` gets properly freed in `_uninit`.

This is a C pattern rather than a C++ pattern as malloc() is a C idiom. C++ uses `new` and `delete`, and this sort of work us usually done in a constructor/destructor pair.

Answer (score 1):

I had issues about this problem for long time. I suggest you to read this wiki page:

[Smart Pointers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer)

In your case you can use unique_ptr. So you would be able to transfer the ownership of the pointer to the caller function.

```
unique_ptr<int> callee1()
{
     std::unique_ptr<int> p1(new int(5));
     return p1;
}

int main()
{
     std::unique_ptr<int> result = callee1() ;
     (*result)++; // Increase the value stored in the pointer
     std::cout << "New Value: " << (*result) << std::endl; 
     result.reset() ;
}
```

Hope this code sniper helps you.